# How to not "cut" / "flatten" lines when moving the spines in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to move the spines of an axes outward a bit, as shown in the bottom example on http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html. However, when I do this, the lines which are close to the axes borders are "cut": It seems like the lines drawn still accommodate for the spine (which isn't there any more). You can see the effect in the plots on the example page I linked above: In the bottom example, the blue line is "flattened" in its maximum and minimum.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the lines are still clipping at the edge of the axes area, even though you have moved the spines away.  You can turn clipping off:

```
ln, = ax.plot(...,)
ln.set_clip_on(False)
```

but you will need to be careful that your axes range and your data range line up (as it will run off to the left and right as well).

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  Maybe it would be nice to have a convenience function in mpl for this, no?